# Facebook create events with several owners with Graph API

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, owner

Is it possible to create an event with the graph API with several owners/promoters ?

It seems to be possible manually so why not using Graph API, but I don't find any docs about that issue...?

Any answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API to change the admins of an event, this can only be done via Facebook's own interface.

Comment: Ok thanks ! After about 2 or 3 hours of researches, that's what I was supposing. I only needed a confirmation. Thanks a lot.